# Using Hydra not sending traffic to target VM

Tags: virtualization, wireshark, hydra

I have 3 VM's

- 1 with Ubuntu server version 20.04, apache2, php, mysql and DVWA. (10.0.2.4)
- 1 with Ubuntu client version 20.04 with hydra installed. (10.0.2.5)
- 1 with Kali 2021.3. (10.0.2.6)

All VM's are at the same Nat Network.

```
hydra 10.0.2.4 -V -l admin -p password http-get-form "/vulnerabilities/brute/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:S=Welcome:H=Cookie:PHPSESSID=8vf4o5ggpc8gsgs9rdtn3kkrrn; security=low"
```

This is the output from the hydra command on the Kali machine:

```
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 task, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking http-get-form://10.0.2.4:80/vulnerabilities/brute/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:S=Welcome:H=Cookie:PHPSESSID=8vf4o5ggpc8gsgs9rdtn3kkrrn; security=low
[ATTEMPT] target 10.0.2.4 - login "admin" - pass "psword" - 1 of 1 [child 0] (0/0)
[STATUS] 1.00 tries/min, 1 tries in 00:01h, 1 to do in 00:01h, 1 active
[STATUS] 0.50 tries/min, 1 tries in 00:02h, 1 to do in 00:01h, 1 active
```

Using Wireshark from the kali machine and then running the hydra command does not show anything in Wireshark as if nothing is sent across the line.

Using `ping`, `wget` or `curl` from the kali box gives output in Wireshark.

The same command run from the other VM works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when i was trying with Hydra v9.1. in 2021.3 Kali.
It seems there is a bug in new kali versions with hydra because no traffic is sent.

I was testing with an old version Hydra v8.6 (2017) in kali and the same hydra command is working fine.

Hydra/Kali should be reviewed in the new kali versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the GitHub for THC-Hydra:

> Note: you need hydra 9.0 - or better 9,2+. hydra 9.1 has a bug in the module and does not work.

So I downloaded the latest version from GitHub, build it, restarted kali and had version 9.3 dev working.

Using the command that failed before is giving positive results now.

So don't use version 9.1 that comes with kali.